# Why is my multiple GET request to the same path not working but only the first one is working?

Tags: node.js, get

These are my codes. I am wondering why is my first GET request only working but the 2nd one is not?

I am trying to pull data from 2 table but want to render them to the same page for 2 different fields.

```
// GET ALL CATEGORIES
  app.get("/company", function (req, res) {
    db.Category.findAll({
      attributes: ["categoryName"],
      raw: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      // res.json(dbCategory);
      var dbCategory = {
        dbCategory: data
      };
      console.log(dbCategory);
      res.render("companyPage", dbCategory);
    });
  });

  // GET ALL MANUFACTURER
  app.get("/company", function (req, res) {
    db.Manufacturer.findAll({
      attributes: ["manufacturerName"],
      raw: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      var dbManufacturer = {
        dbManufacturer: data
      };
      console.log(dbManufacturer);
      res.render("companyPage", dbManufacturer);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET endpoint is not working because you have defined same route.
this problem can be solved using

1.use different route as explain in above answer

2.if you want both operation should be perform on /company then combine two operation under single GET endpoint

check sample code for more reference:

```
// GET ALL CATEGORIES
app.get("/company", function (req, res) {
db.Category.findAll({
  attributes: ["categoryName"],
  raw: true
}).then(function (dbCategory) {
  // GET ALL MANUFACTURER
  db.Manufacturer.findAll({
    attributes: ["manufacturerName"],
    raw: true
  }).then(function (dbManufacturer) {
    var dbStuff = {
      dbCategory,
      dbManufacturer,
      msg: "Christmas Toy Store"
    };
    console.log(dbStuff);
    res.render("companyPage", dbStuff);
  });
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I need them on the same route. Someone else helped to do this way which works fine and is similar to your solution. I edited your code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You can accept this as a answer .

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining same route, you can change the second route and update it accordingly with fields.

```
 // GET ALL CATEGORIES
  app.get("/company", function (req, res) {
    db.Category.findAll({
      attributes: ["categoryName"],
      raw: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      // res.json(dbCategory);
      var dbCategory = {
        dbCategory: data
      };
      console.log(dbCategory);
      res.render("companyPage", dbCategory);
    });
  });

  // GET ALL MANUFACTURER
  app.get("/company/manufacturer", function (req, res) {
    db.Manufacturer.findAll({
      attributes: ["manufacturerName"],
      raw: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      var dbManufacturer = {
        dbManufacturer: data
      };
      console.log(dbManufacturer);
      res.render("companyPage", dbManufacturer);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you get the first path '/compagny'.

If you want the two datas with the same path, you should write all in the same get function.

Try this :

```
app.get("/company", async function (req, res) {
  const dataCategory = db.Category.findAll({
    attributes: ["categoryName"],
    raw: true 
  });
  const dataManufacturer = db.Manufacturer.findAll({
      attributes: ["manufacturerName"],
      raw: true
  });
  const [dbCategory, dbManufacturer] = await Promise.all([dataCategory,dataManufacturer]);
  res.render("companyPage",{
    dbCategory,
    dbManufacturer
  });
});
```